# DRCsim-1.3.1 seems not to work with tutorials

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I just patched to DRCsim-1.3.1, but now when I load up the environment different things happen, all of them bad.  When I just run atlas_utils atlas.launch, the robot loads but falls down, saying l_leg_uhz was not calibrated, and that it's missing drc vehicle and fire_hose_model.  When I run atlas_utils atlas_position_controllers, I get all kinds of controller initialization errors, and again it's missing the vehicle and fire hose.  Not sure what changed, the directory names sure didn't change with the update.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/590/drcsim-1.3.1-seems-not-to-work-with-tutorials/) by [DRC_Justin](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/73/drc_justin/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-01-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The errors about missing the firehose and vehicle models can be ignored.  There's a [pull request](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/pull-request/69/resolve-issue-74-ros-errors-should-be-ros/diff) pending that downgrades them to info messages.

As for the robot falling down; not sure what's going on there.  There's a chance that you're experiencing an ABI-breaking change in the other direction (newly compiled drcsim with older ROS packages).  I would try getting a fresh install of ROS:

```
sudo apt-get remove ros-fuerte-*
sudo apt-get install drcsim
```

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0